# Как определить, что одно слово произошло от другого, а не наоборот?

Tags: словообразование

Мой учебник говорит, что слово *глубь* образовано безаффиксным способом от прилагательного *глубокий*.
Откуда авторы учебника знают, что произошло не наоборот, что сначала было существительное *глубь*, а потом появилось прилагательное *глубокий*?
Нужно ли залезать глубоко в историю русского языка, чтобы доказать это, или есть более общие и простые правила?

Comment: Посмотрите, например, здесь:
http://www.langust.ru/rus_gram/rus_gr06.shtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начнём со статьи в Словаре Даля  :

> Глубина
>
> **глубь**, тамб. сиб. **глыбь**, влгд. **глуб**отина, стар. **глуб**ота ж. высота, вышина, в обратном смысле: протяжение по отвесу сверху вниз, от поверхности до дна.
>   || Пропасть, бездна; пучина, воды морские в огромных земных котловинах.
>   || Бездна, тьма, неисчислимость, неизмеримость, неисчерпаемость;
>   || непостижимость, необъятность, о мысля?х, о премудрости и пр. В глубине души или сердца, скрытое в человеке, незримое.
>
> Глубинный, до глубины относящийся.
>
> Глубокий, глубкий, южн. глыбкий, зап. глыбкой, далекий в глубину, простирающийся вглубь, высокий, меряя сверху вниз; это понятие сравнительное: глубокое море, глубокая рана. *Глубокая печаль; глубокое почтение, м?олчание; глубокий смысл. Глубокая старость. Глубокая ночь.
>
> **Глуб**же стар. глубоче и глубочае, сравнительная степень нареч. глубоко.
>
> Глубоконек, то же, но более в значении излишне глубокий. Тиха вода, да омуты глубоки. Что глубже схоронится семя, то лучше уродится. Рыба ищет где глубже, а человек, где лучше. Глубже пахать - больше хлеба жевать (видать).
>
> Глубокость ж. глубина, глубота, как свойство; более в значении переносном. Глубокость чувств, учения и пр.
>
> **Глуб**ить что, малоупотр. углублять, делать глубже.
>
> **Глуб**енить безлич. становиться глубже. В эту сторону море глубенит, а сюда мельчает.
>
> **Глуб**ник м. арх.-мез. ветер от северо-запада; по этому направлению от Мезени глубина; около Архангельска, это побережник.
>   || На Байкале, глубник, юго-западный ветер.
>
> **Глуб**няк м. глубь, глубина. За мысом глубняк морской.
>
> **Глуб**никовый, до глубника относящийся.
>
> **Глуб**ница ж. арх. вырубки, зарубки в шпангоутах, для свободного стока воды к льялу, где ставится помпа; лимбербордов канал; в лодках и барках, самое льяло, откуда вода вычерпывается плицею.
>
> **Глуб**янка, глубеника ж. сиб. клубника, растение и ягода.
>
> **Глуб**овина пск. яма, ямина.
>
> Синонимы и родственные слова:
>   Глубеника, глубенить, глубже, глубинный, глубить, глубкий, глубник, глубниковый, глубница, глубняк, глубовина, глубокий, глубоко, глубоковатый, глубокомерный, глубокомысленность, глубокомысленный, глубокомыслие, глубоконек, глубокоречивость, глубокоречивый, глубокоречие, глубокость, глубота, глуботина, глубочае, глубоче, глубь, глубянка, глыбкий, глыбко, глыбкой, глыбоко, **глыбь**.

По другим словарям *глубь* по крайней мере с 12 века известна. Корень ГЛУБ первоначален в любом случае(глыба, globus).
[image]

Выводить *глубь* из *глубокий* по меньшей мере **безответственно**.
Суффиксы на то и суффиксы, что к корням присоединяются :
высок, широк, глубок, низок, мелок, робок и тд.

[image]

Comment: Статья М.Эпштейна о русских "словокорнях" : www.emory.edu/INTELNET/mt_logopoeia.html

Comment: Вы статью-то хорошо прочитали? Она о "словотворчестве". Радикалы в основном-неологизмы, он доказывает, что это народ возвращает им исконное значение.Как видите, слова"глубь" там нет и не могло быть.Было прилагательное глубъ, от него глубь с помощью темы-ь.

Comment: Статью Эпштейна я упомянул здесь для "расширения вопроса". Автор в ней рассматривает современное поэтическое словотворчество, попутно вспоминает он и о первоначальных лексических единицах РЯ. Они все обросли со временем морфами, но никто не вправе утверждать, что слова типа *глубь, ярь,топь* вторичные неологизмы, происходящие от прилагательных "глубокий, яркий,топкий". Изучайте древнерусскую лексику и делайте правильные выводы (см. выше *глубь*, Сл. Срезневского, ист. 12 в.)  
П.С. Я всегда читаю статьи, которые предлагаю. А вы "праславянские словари" сами читали где-нибудь? Первоисточники??

Comment: Кажется, скоро будут учить школьников, что существительное *свет* происходит от прилагательного *светлый* путём усечения.

Comment: Для читающих: статья о том, какая филология нам действительно нужна http://www.trinitas.ru/rus/doc/0001/005a/00011433.htm

Answer (score 3):

ОНИ знают историю языка. 
Слово глубокий -- праславянское, глубь образовалось позднее, как и глубина, только глубь с нулевым суффиксом, а глубина - суфф. -ин-.

А вообще мотивирующую основу подбирают с помощью определения слова через данный корень. Попробуйте дать определение. Что такое глубь? - это предмет или состояние с признаком прилагательного глубокий. Отсекаем аффикс - глубь. Ширь - предмет с признаком широкого. Отсекаем аффикс - ширь.

Что такое припев? - это результат действия припевать - бессуффиксный (или безаффиксный). Что такое работа? - результат действия работать.

Answer (score 1):

Отвечаю тут Людмиле. А то длинновато для комментария получилось.

Людмила, а ведь что-то в этой логике не совсем чисто... Ну нельзя же все выводить из "авторитетного мнения". Должно ж быть какое-то более объективное доказательство... Иначе наука превращается в ученье.

Конкретно по примеру. Я голову сломал, почему постулируется первичность глубокий по отношению к "глуби". С "глубиной" все понятно, там более молодой суффикс. А само "глубокий" тогда от чего образовано? Если считать его коренным морфом в паниндоевропейском языке, то от такого морфа наверняка могло образоваться нечто гораздо раньше прилагательного "глубокий", надо ж было как-то само понятие "глубина" обозначать.

А если "глубокий" заимствовано, то откуда  него (пра)славянский суффикс...

Насчет первичности глаголов по отношению к существительным, от них образованным,  тут сомнений нет; глагол - часть речи самодостаточная, может быть первичной ко всему. А насчет некоторых прилагательных, включая это "глубокий"...  Как-то не сходятся концы с концами. Глубокий имеющий глубину (глубь). Как-то логичнее так получается, чем в обратную сторону...

Или это сугубо синхронистский подход, дескать, так в современном языке удобнее трактовать, поскольку прилагательное более распространено в современном языке и потому считаем его первичным? Тогда при чем тут история языка?

Comment: Вы меня удивили. Первичны существительные конкретные, а глубь - абстрактное. Насчёт авторитетного мнения: не люблю изобретать велосипед, пусть профессионалы-учёные "роют историю", честно говоря, для меня истор. грамматика всегда и в институте была трудна, я лучше посмотрю у Фасмера и Цыганенко, они диссертации писали, копали глубоко. У Цыганенко: слово глубокий первонач. могло иметь знач. "выдолбленный, вырытый", "углубленный". Параллельно прил. глубъ (или от него) с пом. темы -ь образовано сущ.глубь "глубина" как нов - новь. http://lib.co.ua/dict/cyganenkogp/etimologicheskiyslovarrusskogo.js

Comment: Было др.-р. прилагательноеглубъ. От него сущ.глубь и параллельно(позднее) кратк форма глубок, от него совр.глубокий. А когда и под влиянием чего формы стали принимать совр. вид, даже разбираться не хочу. Главное-от прилагательного, а коли в совр яз. нет уже прил.ГЛУБ, зачит, от совр.глубокий.

Comment: У Цыганенко ИЛИ, потому что параллельное образование памятниками не доказано, но мнение есть.

Answer (score 0):

Суффиксы с абстрактным значением появляются позже в истории развития любого языка, поэтому можно говорить о том, что слово "глубокий" появилось раньше, чем слово "глубь".